# Why do these words break in strange places?

Tags: css, word-wrap, word-break, css-hyphens

Here's the live site: http://chadfraser.com/

As you can see, if you look on mobile or scale your browser window, the words break in strange places.  I could add hyphens, except my client is a professional writer and doesn't want them.  We shouldn't need them though - I can't figure out why the words won't just wrap with the white space.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: I cannot reproduce what you're saying, looks good to me.

Comment: Nothing breaks for me - in firefox

Comment: Can reproduce on Chrome with small window sizes. You have `word-wrap: break-word` somewhere in your CSS.

Comment: You're right @MultiplyByZer0, I do have that in my body {} tag.  But then when I remove it, the text flows outside the div. I can't set the max-width of the container - still flows outside (you'll see what I mean if you remove the word-wrap in firebug.  I don't understand why the white space won't cause a wrap.

Comment: This is how I see the website with the window scaled on Firefox https://www.dropbox.com/s/yiuhtjub4ymg45i/teste.png?dl=1~. I've tested it on Chrome and it looks good too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its because your code is assigning `word-wrap: break-word;` It causes the word to break in half if necessary.

Most precisely, it is been set in *styles.css* on line 51:

```
body {
    word-wrap: break-word;
    ...
```

So, your entire document will behave like this. Set the property to `word-wrap: normal` on the elements you don't want to break, or just remove this property from the body

Comment: If I do that in firebug, the text flows way outside the container, causing the page to scroll horizontally.  Why doesn't the white space cause a wrap between the words? It's acting like it's one giant word.

Comment: This is what it looks like as-is: http://imgur.com/kA5XiZx.  This is what it looks like when I set the h3 tag to `word-wrap: normal`: http://imgur.com/q4DKES5

Comment: @jay - The problem is because in the text, instead of white spaces you have `&nbsp;`.. That keeps the break from happening. Replace it for real white spaces and see

Comment: Unbelievable.  Wordpress (even in the html editor) wasn't showing that and I missed it (because firebug wasn't either).  Thank you so much.  All fixed!